# converting ASCII Hex string to __int64 in Java/Spring Boot

Tags: java

I got an ASCII hex binary string "60A01805000000000" create by a cpp module.
Now I want to read that string in Java and get back it's original value which is 855000.

Can someone let me know how can we achieve that?

Comment: `60A01805000000000` is 17 characters (an `__int64` should have 16). Even if I remove one `0` at the end, converting it back gives `85500000`, not `855000`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(java.lang.String,%20int) or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: If you'd like you clarify the question, that'd be great. How are those 17 characters supposed to be translated to `855000`?